# Android: Get Gender & Age

Tags: android

I'm looking for an easy way to get user's gender & age programmatically without any user input. I do not want to trouble the user with any sort of sign-ins to G+, FB or Twitter.

Just need a quick and easy way to get gender & age.

Is there any way to get user's gender and age without requiring any account sign-ins?

Are there any SDK's that would give this info without sign-ins?

Comment: Yes, there is. A popup window asking gender and age.

Comment: @SvSv thanks, but I meant programmatically without user input. I'll add this clarification to the question :)

Comment: Did you have an idea in your mind of where this data could come from, if not from social media or user input?

Comment: Do you want the user to tell you or do you plan to get it from somewhere on the user's device? I would recommend the first option with a very basic implementation, maybe just an Activity or a Fragment with 2 text fields or spinners.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any. You have interact with user to get the details, either by sign in or asking by yourself.

In some cases, you can however get some details, there is a contact, called as User which a few users fill. It might have the information you require but it is mostly empty.

But you shouldn't use this as it might be against user's will. You should use sign in or input fields.

Comment: If we can't use, why the big companies can do?! Google, FB, and others...

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for getting this information for statistical purposes, I'd recommend using Firebase analytics. Firebase automatically gives you age and gender distributions of your users.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Is there any way to access this from Firebase programmatically at run-time?

Comment: But even when using that information, it's still a statistic value. It does not tell you who is using your app ATM. You won't get this information without interacting with the user

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any information without the user giving them to you (either with stating them in the app or giving you permission to take them). As @Sahil stated, IF the user has a contact with that information in order to take them you must get contacts permissions, which is not very smart having in mind that you only need users age and gender. The best way is to have a dialog or something similar where the user will state this informations.

Comment: Lets say I already have the contacts permission, how would I do it then?

Comment: As I have never done this, hypothetically if you retrieve the whole list of contact you will get he "me" contact also (this is IF the user has stated that information), but if you don't use the contacts for other things inside the app, go with plain simple asking the user to input those.